# Silverstripe 3: How can you unpublish pages on a set date?

Tags: silverstripe

I want to set pages to unpublish automatically at a set date on silverstripe 3.

I have seen multiple solutions for this online, mostly with the use of certain modules however none of these are compatible with silverstripe 3 and a lot of the modules say they are now abandoned, if not I get the following error on composer

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                        
  Could not find a matching version of package xxxxxxxx. Check the package spelling, your version constr  
  aint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (dev).
```

Does anyone have a fully working solution for silverstripe 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are looking for is most likely the embargo module (https://github.com/silverstripe-terraformers/silverstripe-embargo-expiry). In combination with the queuedjobs modules (https://github.com/symbiote/silverstripe-queuedjobs) for scheduled jobs allows to schedule publishing and unpublishing of DataObjects (for example pages).

You can install the modules with:

```
composer require silverstripe-terraformers/embargo-expiry symbiote/silverstripe-queuedjobs
```

and add the configuration to the SiteTree:

```
SiteTree:
  extensions:
    - SilverStripe\Versioned\Versioned
    - Terraformers\EmbargoExpiry\Extension\EmbargoExpiryExtension
```

Run dev/build afterwards and you should be able to set dates in the CMS.

On your production environment you will need to ensure to configure a cronjob similar to this:

```
*/1 * * * * php /path/to/silverstripe-project/framework/cli-script.php dev/tasks/ProcessJobQueueTask
```

For local testing you should be able to run:

```
php ./framework/cli-script.php dev/tasks/ProcessJobQueueTask
```

With the steps above you should be able to have expiry of pages set up in SilverStripe 3.x.

Cheers,
Peter